# Can i display the CallLog numbers in my edittext? New here

Tags: android, button, android-intent, android-edittext, calllog

- I have created a simple xml with one button and one edittext.
- Upon clicking the button, i can get into the CallLog page.
- Is it possible to display the selected numbers into my EditText, after i click on any numbers in my CallLog??

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:baselineAligned="true"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText
android:id="@+id/edittext"
android:layout_width="172dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="0.29"
android:hint="CONTACT NUMBER" >

<requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="CALL LOG" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Coding:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class CallLogRetrieveActivity extends Activity {

Button myCallLogBtn;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

myCallLogBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

myCallLogBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent myIntent=new Intent();
        myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL_BUTTON);
        startActivity(myIntent);

    }});
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start reading manual and tutorial first, not asking here about elementary things that you'd simply know after doing RTFM. So "yes, you can". But now please do your homework, by reading "android call log tutorial" googled materials. Nobody here is going that for you.